# Can i build three keras models in same script?

Tags: python, keras

I had a small question, I have 3 of the same dataset, but one has been filtered assuming 10% outlier fraction, then 15% then 20%. I need to compare the mean squared error for each. I was thinking of building the same keras model 3 times in the same script, and run each individiually. I wanted to do so because I wanted to produce a graph at the end with epochs number on the x-axis, and the mse values of each dataset on y-axis, all in the same figure. is that possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is absolutely possible, just name your models accordingly i.e. instead of `model.fit()` use `model_1.fit()` for dataset 1, `model_2.fit()` for dataset 2 etc

Comment: Great! but for example when I'm plotting, I have the following code for 1 database 
 ` plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.show()  `
then how would I plot all 3 on same figure?

Comment: @AliYoussef, why do not you search before you ask? There are plenty of resources for this.